# What's the usage of `expect_before` command in Expect?

Tags: expect

The doc says:

> takes the same arguments as `expect`, however it returns immediately.

But what does it mean by "returns immediately" ?

What's the usage of this command could be ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Image you have spawned a program that, say, randomly asks "Are you sure [yn]?"
Imagine this program has 100 questions that need to be answered.

You don't want to have to *conditionally* expect an "Are you sure" question for each of those 100 questions.

Expect lets you do:

```
spawn /some/annoying/program

expect_before {
    "Are you sure \[yn]?" {
        send "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
}

expect "first question"
send "first answer\r"
# and so on.
```

Now you are covered: expect *implicitly* adds the `expect_before` code into *each* `expect` command.

Comment: Thanks! What does it mean by "returns immediately" ?

Comment: Expect does not stop and wait for the spawned process to output "Are you sure"